# How to point SSL Enabled custom Sub Domains to Elastic Beanstalk? (without Route53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cpanel

I am trying to map an external *sub domain* into my **Elastic Beanstalk** Environment. I know, the common way is to use **Route53** but I see no use of using it when my client's domain provider has already provided **CPanel** and stuff to set the `CName` and things. So, I am about to follow the below method to set domain to **Beanstalk**.

1. Login to your provider website and select your domain
2. Click on "Advanced DNS"
3. Create a CNAME record.
4. host: www
   value: {{enter-your-subdomain}}.elasticbeanstalk.com.
5. Create a URL Redirect record.
   host: @
   value: http://www.{{your-custom-domain}}.com

By doing the above, I expect to have ***subdomain.example.com*** instead of ***subdomain-region.elasticbeanstalk.com***

You can see detailed info in this - https://colintoh.com/blog/map-custom-domain-to-elastic-beanstalk-application

I am going to apply this to 2 things.

1. The REST API which resides in Beanstalk. (Will be used by few mobile and web apps)
2. The Web Portal app which resides in Beanstalk.

Now, I can see my client already has couple of subdomains for other purposes with SSL enabled. They have purchased SSL from a CA. Therefor, can we enable SSL in CPanel and point the SSL enabled sub domains to Beanstalk? Or we have to reconfigure everything in Route53 and go through their complex process of setting up the SSL?

Comment: You would need to download those SSL certs and upload to ALB of your Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Just to mentioned, that AWS ACM issues SSL certs for free and if you instead use Route 53 + ACM it will be very smooth in my opinion. You would need to do following :
 - Zone delegation for the sub-domain you want to manage in Route 53.
 - DNS validated ACM certificate creation in AWS ACM.

Comment: @why domain redirection wont work? Also, using Route53 means I will have to change the nameservers of the domain right? Thats now something possible, because the client has his site and some other things under this domain which has nothing to do with AWS. Also about the ACM certificate, they say not to use in production environments.

Comment: By domain redirection, I think you mean a 302 redirect. In that case, in my understanding by default AWS will pickup the default SSL certs attached to the ALB of your Beanstalk. So that would mean that the client (say Chrome) will see a change in the domain name on the browser to xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com instead of yourdomain.com . If that is okay with you, then it would work fine I think. And you do not need to changes your nameservers for the domain. You can just a Zone Delegation for a specific sub-domain via SOA record in your current registrar.

Comment: If you do not want a 302 redirect, then a CNAME entry + adding SSL certs to Elastic BeanStalk should do the work (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl-upload.html) .

Comment: @Siddharth: Thanks. Regarding the last comment, it is about uploading to IAM, but since ACM is available in my region, I think ACM will work. Can you provide your point as an answer, with some info on zone delegation to Route53 and ACM process? Then everyone can see it clearly

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: @Siddharth: Appreciate to have step by step process, considering I already have a CA certificate purchased from Comodo or somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212956/discussion-between-siddharth-and-lemon-juice).

Answer (score 0):

## Using SSL certificates issued by external vendor

From the side of SSL vendor you would need three files : certificate-chain.pem, https-cert.crt and private-key.pem .

Steps would be as follows:

1. Import certificate to ACM

   `aws acm import-certificate –certificate file://https-cert.crt
   –private-key file://private-key.pem –certificate-chain
   file://certificate-chain.pem`
2. Once the import is complete to edit Load Balancer settings in AWS Elasticbeanstalk from Console to choose the imported certificate. For detailed step by step instruction refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html .

## Using SSL certificates from AWS ACM

Steps would be as follows:

1. Create a Public Hosted Zone in Route 53 with the subdomain in discussion (say app.mydomain.com). AWS will return multiple ns server names.
2. Create an SOA record in the existing domain registrar for app.mydomain.com pointing to the ns server names returned in step 1.
3. Go to ACM and create domain validated certificates for app.mydomain.com .
4. Edit Load Balancer settings in AWS Elasticbeanstalk from Console to choose the new ACM certificates. For detailed step by step instruction refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html .

Comment: I think we can also get free public certificates from them as well right? Are they really free or some charge?

Comment: For public certificates issued by Amazon there is no charge. But if you create Private CA then there is a charge. You can read the details at https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/ .